# I want to split the dataset in a such a way that class ratio is maintained in Pytorch

Tags: image, class, split, dataset, pytorch

I want to split the dataset in a such a way that class ratio is maintained. 
Suppose the following:

```
Total Image: 500, Class A 300; Class B 200
----------
Train: 300 (Class A 180, Class B 120)
----------
Valid: 100 (Class A 60, Class B 40)
----------
Test:100  (Class A 60, Class B 40)
```

In my case Total Train, valid and test ratio is maintained, but not the class ratio

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for sklearn's [`test_train_split`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) which has the ability to maintain class ratio via the `stratify` parameter.

In your case you'll have to split twice, once to split off test data, and again to split between validation and train.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Create a dataset with your requirements
X = np.random.randn(500)
a = [0] * 300
b = [1] * 200
y = a + b

# Take 100 elements for the test set
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, stratify=y)

# Take 100 elements (from the remaining 400) for the validation set
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.25, stratify=y_train)

print(len(y_train)) # 300
print(len(y_val))   # 100
print(len(y_test))  # 100

print(sum(y_train)) # 120 (120 class B, 180 class A)
print(sum(y_val))   # 40  (40 class B, 60 class A)
print(sum(y_test))  # 40  (40 class B, 60 class A)
```